# sphinx-argparse: get rid of headers: Positional, Named Arguments

Tags: python-sphinx

I want to update sphinx-argparse to be able to use `:nodescription:`.

However, when I update the package I get something like this:

[image: screen shot 2017-09-04 at 3 18 26 pm]

is there a way to get rid of these arguments, and keep it as it was before?

Like here https://rna-pdb-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html#cluster

Does any one know how to do it?

Comment: I learn something more "In newer version, all of the sections are linkable, whereas they weren't in old versions. A side-effect of linkability is possible inclusion in the table of contents." https://github.com/ribozz/sphinx-argparse/issues/78#issuecomment-326969984